# 'Incomplete' where clause still runs

Tags: mysql, sql

I accidentally built the following sql but it still runs. The query returns all records from a mysql database. Where would this type of query be used?

```
SELECT student_2.Name
     , student_2.Student_ID   
  FROM student student_2 
 WHERE student_2.Student_ID
```

The query I wanted to build is this one:

```
SELECT student_2.Name
     , student_2.Student_ID  
  FROM student student_2 
 WHERE student_2.Student_ID = ?
```

? being some integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL treats *boolean* as a valid type.  In general, booleans are converted to integers, with `0` for false and `1` for true.  In fact, `0` is false, and any non-`NULL` value other than `0` is true.

What your condition is really saying is:

```
where student_2.Student_ID <> 0
```

That means that any non-0, non-`NULL` value will match.

This is sometimes used with functions that return `0` for a non-match.  So, sometimes you will find:

```
where find_in_set(id, @ids)
```

rather than:

```
where find_in_set(id, @ids) > 0
```

Note that this is a MySQL extension to standard SQL, so most other databases would not support this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Since you left it empty consider this as writing `WHERE 1 = 1` or `WHERE true` which will give you everything back

Comment: Not really. See Gordon's answer. His explanation is correct.